# Choose the correct answer from a, b, c or d:-

Tags: word-choice

**John went on ..... driving a car.
[ a) a two-hour - b) two-hour - c) two-hours - d) a two-hours ]**

Comment: I think it's a test, are you cheating?

Comment: None of them seems right. Is this copied correctly? What is the context?

Comment: @Andy Semyonov: No, I'm not. I just found this question in my textbook and it got me confused, so I'm here for some clarification.

Comment: @Shoe : That's what I thought too.

Comment: John went on two hours, driving a car. That would be correct.

Comment: Heba. The question would make sense if the gapped sentence read: _John went on ... in his car_.

Comment: This is proofreading, not a question.

Comment: It might have originated as proofreading, but there are questions in there nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...driving a car for two hours" or "for two hours, driving a car" would be usual, so I have to wonder about the textbook you have.

Comment: It could be a very straightforward sentence, where least care is given to prepositions.

Comment: OK, if we assumed that  'went on' is a phrasal verb, would 'two-hours' then be the answer that best makes sense? (oh, and sorry about my English, as it's not my mother tongue).

Comment: "went on driving for two hours" would be fine. But! if "two hours" has some special import, you might say "went on the driving those two hours". "She gabbed without stop for what seemed like ages, but he went on driving those two hours, clenching his teeth."

Comment: FumbleFingers has written: ]. Premature pre-emptive answers are no benefit to the site, so I [can’t] see any problem with them being downvoted if they don't answer the "final, clarified" question. If nothing else, this might discourage those hasty answerers from leaving what eventually amounts to "litter" on the site.  FF >> Since Shoe asks for clarification (None of them seems right. Is this copied correctly? What is the context?), this question is obviously not suitable for ELU as it stands. And it's very basic.  Answering it devalues the site.